# my MYSQL my.cnf file doesnt contain bind address on it, and when i put it in the file, it wouldnt work

Tags: mysql

My `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file had no bind-address when i checked it. when i placed the bind-address, it wouldn't restart the process with an error.

when i try the command mysql i get this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
root@vps687459:~#
```

when i try to restart the service, it gives me this:

```
Sep 02 13:14:34 vps687459 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 02 13:14:34 vps687459 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 02 13:14:34 vps687459 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Sep 02 13:14:35 vps687459 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 02 13:14:35 vps687459 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Sep 02 13:14:35 vps687459 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Sep 02 13:14:35 vps687459 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 02 13:14:35 vps687459 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 02 13:14:35 vps687459 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#

# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

all i want is to be able to connect to my database from another machine. how can i fix my community server to do this

EDIT: I got this error:

```
mysql: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 23!
```

i Then checked my my.cnf:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Why doesn't mysqld start? Try getting a glimpse of the error through logs in `/var/log/mysql*` or `journalctl -b -p 0..3`

Comment: @DanielW. i've edited the question now with that error.

Comment: The errors have nothing to do with mysqld, they are coming from sshd. Please look for the mysqld error.

Comment: @DanielW. there i believe i found the mysql error.

Comment: you will find the bind address directive in one of the cnf files in either `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` or `/etc/mysql/conf.d`. Avoid touching the file you are editing

Answer (score 0):

In the config files there must be a group preceding prior to the config keys so the interpreter of the config files knows the context:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

This is due to the fact that you can add configuration for `mysql` (client), `mysqld` (server) and other programs like `mysqldump`.